# Alternatives to Apple CloudKit Private Database

Tags: firebase, cloudkit

CloudKit offers a storage space which does not belong to the service provider, but to the user.

I would use this storage, but many of my user does not have iCloud. Is it any similar sulution at Google, to offer the same service to Android / web users?

Those data that are stored in private DB, service provider is not responsable, right?

So i.e. links to Instagram profiles could be stored there, as bookmarks, without violating any GDPR rule?